# How to configure Oracle's Database Network Encryption with MyBatis?

Tags: oracle, encryption, jdbc, connection, mybatis

I have a requirement to encrypt the data in transit between the web server and the database server using Mybatis as the persistence framework.

The database server is Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit.  I am using the ojdbc7.jar driver.

I am able to establish an encrypted connection as described here... https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/asojbdc.htm#DBSEG9613.  However, I have not been able to do so through MyBatis.  I am setting the connection properties in the mybatis-config.xml file.  Below are the contents of that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN' 'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd'>

<configuration>
<settings>
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
    <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL"/>
</settings>
<environments default="development">     
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<server>:<port>/<service>"/>
            <property name="username" value="<username>"/>
            <property name="password" value="<password>"/>
            <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="20"/>
            <property name="poolMaximumIdleConnections" value="10"/>
            <property name="poolMaximumCheckoutTime" value="180000"/>
            <property name="poolPingQuery" value="select 0 from dual"/>
            <property name="poolPingEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="poolPingConnectionsNotUsedFor" value="1800000"/>
            <property name="CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL" value="REQUIRED"/>
            <property name="CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES" value="AES256"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
</configuration>
```

The last two property elements are my attempt at configuring an encrypted connection.  Without them I am able to connect successfully without encryption.  With the last two property elements I just get an error:

> Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: ###
>   Error building SqlSession. ### The error may exist in SQL Mapper
>   Configuration ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException:
>   Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.datasource.DataSourceException: Unknown DataSource
>   property: CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the JDBC properties are not quite right. Note that they can be found in the JavaDoc under oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection. You can try these:

EDIT: as Chris explained in this comments MyBatis requires the driver's property name to be prefixed with "driver".

```
<property name="driver.oracle.net.encryption_client" value="REQUIRED"/>
<property name="driver.oracle.net.encryption_types_client" value="(AES256)"/>
```

Comment: I found what was missing.  I asked the question on the MyBatis User Group and Jeff Butler informed me that you have to prefix driver specific properties with "driver.".  `                <property name="driver.oracle.net.encryption_client" value="REQUIRED"/>
                <property name="driver.oracle.net.encryption_types_client" value="(AES256)"/>`  When I did that, it worked.  @Jean , you were so close to the right answer, if you just edit your answer with the correction, I'll check yours as the correct solution.  Also, you need to put the close tag, "/>" at the end of the elements.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!